# How do I define a monadic function to work on a list in J?

Tags: j, tacit-programming

Let's say I have the following J expression:

```
# 3 ((|=0:)#]) 1+i.1000
```

This counts the number of numbers between 1 and 1000 that are evenly divisible by 3. (Now, before anyone points out that there's an easier way to do this, this question is about *the syntax of J*, and *not* mathematics.)

Let's say I define a monadic function for this, as follows:

```
f =: monad define
# y ((|=0:)#]) 1+i.1000
)
```

This works great with a single argument, e.g.,

```
    f 4
250
```

If I pass a list in, I get a length error:

```
    f 1 2 3
|length error: f
```

Now, I completely understand why I get the length error. When you substitute the list `1 2 3` for the `y` argument of the monad, you get:

```
# 1 2 3 ((|=0:)#]) 1+i.1000
```

If you know anything about J, it's pretty clear why the length error is occurring. So, I don't need an explanation of that.

I want to define the function such that when I pass a list, it returns a list, e.g.,

```
   f 1 2 3
1000 500 333
```

How can I either (a) redefine this function to take a list and return a list or (b) get the function to work on a list as-is without being redefined, perhaps using some adverb or other technique?

Comment: I just realized that the real answer is `f"0 ] 1 2 3` using the _rank_ conjunction. (The superfluous `]` prevents me from having to use parentheses.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for (b) case:

```
    (f@{. , $:@}.) ^: (0 < #) 1 2 3
1000 500 333
```

Comment: Wow. I didn't know you could say `(0<#)`! I thought you had to say `(0:<#)`. Pretty cool.

Comment: @Gregory Higley: Since verbs in J are applied to arguments from right to left, `(0 < #) 1 2 3` is the same as `0 < (# 1 2 3)` or `0 < # 1 2 3`. `(0: < #)` which you suggested in turn is a *fork* we were talking about [in here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864835). Consider also `3 * 5 + 2`, it's evaluated to `21` ;)

Comment: It is necessary to see (0 < #) as a special form of a fork, rather than saying the parentheses don't matter. The latest version of J treats the noun in the expression as a verb. It's a rare case of syntactic sugar in J; (noun verb verb) is interpreted as (noun"_ verb verb)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the much simpler approach of defining your verb as rank zero. Working with the verb you provided, here's a simple way to do that:

```
   f =: monad define "0
# y ((|=0:)#]) 1+i.1000
)

   f 1 2 3
1000 500 333
```

The only change is the `"0` added after the word 'define'.

Comment: Knowing the desired behaviour of the function makes it easier to decide to define it as rank 0. That being said, I'd have simply used `f every` or `f"0`.