# How to pick out all the negative numbers in a list in J?

Tags: j

For example, I have 125 stock returns and I need to calculate the downside standard deviation so I need to pick up all the negative returns. How to do that?

Answer (score 4):

```
0 (>: # ]) _1 2 3 _4 9 2
```

Produces the following output.

```
_1 _4
```

For more information, check out this really informative post [How to filter a list in J?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864835/how-to-filter-a-list-in-j).